# Maximise rigidity of tube/rod

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

I understand that for a given quantity of material a tube is stronger than a rod.

I have a 1.4m clear acrylic rod with 16mm diameter however it is too flexible for its intended purpose (imagine supporting the ends and hanging a weight from the center).

Is it possible to increase/maximise rigidity through either increasing the diameter (max 25mm) and/or making it hollow?

Length must remain constant, and lower weight is preferable but not hard requirement.

Comment: This seems like an [engineering.se] issue rather than a physics one. If you post there on our sister site, please ensure to take their tour and read-up in their help centre before posting. You'll probably be asked for more details before it can be answered.